# Split time series by python or by keras?

Tags: python, keras, time-series

In Python you can use [TimeSeriessplit()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html) to split a time series properly for training but you can also do the same(?) in Keras by [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator).
Which one is recommendable? And/or what are certain differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they can both do what you want them for (can perform the correct splits for your needs), I would recommend simply using the one that fits best with your pipeline. E.g. the data is being fed straight into a Keras model, just do as much as possible in Keras -> use the [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator). Otherwise, stick to Sci-kit Learn.

The both **generate** the splits, meaning they only actually create each *split* as you loop through the data. This saves memory.

Looking at [**the source code of the Keras variant**](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f295e8ee39d4ba841ac281a9337d69c7bc5e0eb6/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L305), it doesn't seem to support running on the GPU if you combine e.g. with your Tensorflow graph - meaning there really isn't a big difference between the two, just the APIs/functionality.